# Visual Studio 2008 Express Not compiling dll with Target framework

Tags: .net, dotpeek

I have a c# project `Authenticate` with below configuration files, which am trying to compile with target framework `.Net 2.0` for Any CPU, it keeps generating the `.Net 3.5` dll instead of `.Net 2.0`(decompiled dll with dotPeek)

Below is my `Authenticate.csproj`

```
<VisualStudioProject>
    <CSHARP
        ProjectType = "Local"
        ProductVersion = "7.0.9466"
        SchemaVersion = "1.0"
        ProjectGuid = "{DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}"
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
    >
        <Build>
            <Settings
                ApplicationIcon = ""
                AssemblyKeyContainerName = ""
                AssemblyName = "Authenticate"
                AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile = ""
                DefaultClientScript = "JScript"
                DefaultHTMLPageLayout = "Grid"
                DefaultTargetSchema = "IE50"
                DelaySign = "false"
                OutputType = "Library"
                RootNamespace = "Authenticate"
                StartupObject = ""
            >
                <Config
                    Name = "Debug"
                    AllowUnsafeBlocks = "false"
                    BaseAddress = "285212672"
                    CheckForOverflowUnderflow = "false"
                    ConfigurationOverrideFile = ""
                    DefineConstants = "DEBUG;TRACE"
                    DocumentationFile = ""
                    DebugSymbols = "true"
                    FileAlignment = "4096"
                    IncrementalBuild = "true"
                    Optimize = "false"
                    OutputPath = "bin\Debug\"
                    RegisterForComInterop = "false"
                    RemoveIntegerChecks = "false"
                    TreatWarningsAsErrors = "false"
                    WarningLevel = "4"
                />
                <Config
                    Name = "Release"
                    AllowUnsafeBlocks = "false"
                    BaseAddress = "285212672"
                    CheckForOverflowUnderflow = "false"
                    ConfigurationOverrideFile = ""
                    DefineConstants = "TRACE"
                    DocumentationFile = ""
                    DebugSymbols = "false"
                    FileAlignment = "4096"
                    IncrementalBuild = "false"
                    Optimize = "true"
                    OutputPath = "bin\Release\"
                    RegisterForComInterop = "false"
                    RemoveIntegerChecks = "false"
                    TreatWarningsAsErrors = "false"
                    WarningLevel = "4"
                />
            </Settings>
            <References>
                <Reference
                    Name = "System"
                    AssemblyName = "System"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\System.dll"
                />
                <Reference
                    Name = "System.Data"
                    AssemblyName = "System.Data"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\System.Data.dll"
                />
                <Reference
                    Name = "System.XML"
                    AssemblyName = "System.Xml"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\System.XML.dll"
                />
                <Reference
                    Name = "System.Web"
                    AssemblyName = "System.Web"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\System.Web.dll"
                />
                <Reference
                    Name = "DataCertSettings"
                    AssemblyName = "DataCertSettings"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\POC\bin\Client\Settings.dll"
                />
                <Reference
                    Name = "CertUtil"
                    AssemblyName = "CertUtil"
                    HintPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\POC\bin\Client\CertUtil.dll"
                />
            </References>
        </Build>
        <Files>
            <Include>
                <File
                    RelPath = "AssemblyInfo.cs"
                    SubType = "Code"
                    BuildAction = "Compile"
                />
                <File
                    RelPath = "AuthenticateModule.cs"
                    SubType = "Code"
                    BuildAction = "Compile"
                />
            </Include>
        </Files>
    </CSHARP>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

Below is my `Authenticate.sln`

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Web Developer Express 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Authenticate", "Authenticate.csproj", "{DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DAB9C947-0D3D-416A-A3B4-6DDE536FB208}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I tried compiling the project with VS2010,VS2013 and VS2017. I see the same `.Net 3.5` dll being generated instead of `.Net 2.0`. Can someone please help me to generate `.Net 2.0` dll?

Comment: Under Properties -> Application of your Authenticate project in Visual Studio, what is your Target framework value?

Comment: .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: What about the dll files, DateCertSettings and CertUtil

Comment: I see the  `.Net 3.5` dll being generated  for Target framework value `.Net Framework 2.0 ` on  VS2008,VS2010,VS2013 and VS2017.

Comment: Microsoft no more supports raw .NET Framework 2.0. So valid assemblies must be compiled against .NET Framework 3.5.1 or 4.5.2 and above. So dotPeek might be smart/stupid enough to just say your assembly is against .NET Framework 3.5 (as anyway the CLR version is the same).

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the response, I thought my legacy application is on `.Net 2.0` but apparently its on `.Net 1.1`, is there a way to generate `.Net 1.1` DLL using VS2005 or VS 2008?

Comment: .NET Framework 1.x is long dead. Upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: It actually targets .NET 1.0, v1.0.3705 was its version number.  That you use a VS version that can't support it and just ignores it is not much of a  surprise.  Back-compat is sacred.  Not actually having .NET 2.0 installed on the machine is no surprise either, it is a dead dodo.  And dotPeek doesn't know how to figure it out, it is not imprinted on the executable files at all since you only ever target a CLR version.  You don't have a real problem.